# Regex ignores next match

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

I need help with .NET RegEx to extract info.

The text I match describe a PowerShell-function, and are used for a GUI. So the matches are added to an object as parameters. Each parameter are described as follows:

- The name is the first word after period. This is `InfoType`.
- If `InfoType` is `.InputData`, the next word is a variable name, followed by a description of that variable
- Parameter description is all text up to next `InfoType`
- If there are no words after `InfoType`, like for "NoRunspace", InputVar and InputComment should be empty.

The best pattern I have come up with so far (see below) removes/ignores the next `InfoType`-match after `.NoRunspace`.

Pattern:

```
(?m)^\s*\.(?<InfoType>(?!(Parameter)|(Outputs))\w+)\s*((?<InputVar>\w+)\s*?(?<InputComment>.*))*
```

Text:

```
.Synopsis
    Jämför behörighetsgrupper mellan användare
.MenuItem
    Jämför behörighetsgrupper
.Description
    Jämför behörighetsgrupper mellan användare
.SearchedItemRequest
    Allowed
.OutputType
    ObjectList
.InputData
    Användare Lista på användare, separeras med mellanslag
.NoRunspace
.Author
    Some One (Else)
```

Output I get:

```
Synopsis            : Jämför behörighetsgrupper mellan användare
MenuItem            : Jämför behörighetsgrupper
Description         : Jämför behörighetsgrupper mellan användare
SearchedItemRequest : Allowed
OutputType          : ObjectList
NoRunspace          : 
Author              : Some One (Else)
```

Output I want:

```
Synopsis            : Jämför behörighetsgrupper mellan användare
MenuItem            : Jämför behörighetsgrupper
Description         : Jämför behörighetsgrupper mellan användare
SearchedItemRequest : Allowed
OutputType          : ObjectList
NoRunspace          : 
InputData           : Användare Lista på användare, separeras med mellanslag
Author              : Some One (Else)
```

For some reason "InputData" is not matched, so I can't use it from the text.

How do I change the pattern to also include the text after "NoRunspace"?

Comment: Please ask a specific question ending with `?` character and also show expected output of the text above as I'm not sure if the problem is just the last "`InfoType`" not matching or anything else.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Idem. I get the first three requirements, but not the fourth (i.e. "*this should be handled as a PowerShell function switch-parameter*"); though this could just because I don't know PowerShell. Perhaps you mean a lookahead conditional group, like [this](https://regex101.com/r/8sZTA7/1)?

Comment: Use `Regex.Matces` or `Select-String -AllMatches`.

Comment: I don't think this is even typical PowerShell as normally you'd use `.INPUTS`/`.PARAMETER` and `.OUTPUTS` in help block.

Comment: If you'd use [standard comment based help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-7.3) format, you could use `Get-Help` for parsing, instead of having to reinvent the wheel. `Get-Help` actually returns an object that you can query. It contains function description, array of parameters and so on.

Comment: Can't see your code but your regex matches all the Dot InfoTypes in the sample text. https://regex101.com/r/2ulAsd/1

Comment: I rewrote the surrounding logic and was then able to follow Santiago's suggestion.
For my purpose, the default command based help doesn't work and if I add something to CBH, Get-Help can't parse the text.
I did try Regex101 works, but when I run it in PS 5.1, it does not work.

Comment: Remember that regex101.com uses the _exact_ same engine that you would use if you used that engine. To have all of them work except 1 is a dubious claim. I don't care how you used it.